# How to pull specific data from JSON output?

Tags: python, json, flash-message

I've been working on a simple weather web app using flask and python.

One of the routes I have in my main.py file is the weather route. It has a function that calls the weather api, and prints the json output.

My problem is pulling specific data out of the json output. This is what the output looks like:

```
{'base': 'stations',
 'clouds': {'all': 90},
 'cod': 200,
 'coord': {'lat': 40.73, 'lon': -73.99},
 'dt': 1557824237,
 'id': 5128581,
 'main': {'humidity': 93,
          'pressure': 1009,
          'temp': 43.93,
          'temp_max': 46,
          'temp_min': 42.01},
 'name': 'New York',
 'sys': {'country': 'US',
         'id': 4026,
         'message': 0.0144,
         'sunrise': 1557826807,
         'sunset': 1557878678,
         'type': 1},
 'visibility': 12874,
 'weather': [{'description': 'mist', 'icon': '50n', 'id': 701, 'main': 'Mist'},
             {'description': 'light intensity drizzle',
              'icon': '09n',
              'id': 300,
              'main': 'Drizzle'}],
 'wind': {'deg': 20, 'speed': 8.05}}
```

I used pprint to make it a little more readable. What I am trying to do is pull the "description" data by creating a python dictionary.

```
weather = {
    'city': city,
    'temperature': r['main']['temp'],
    'description': r['weather'][1]['description'],
    'icon': r['weather'][1]['icon'],
    }
```

When I print weather, I expect it to print out `description: light intensity drizzle`, `icon: 09n`, `id:300`, but I get a key error. I don't get a key error when I use "0" instead of "1" but I am trying to pull the second description data, not the first. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let&#39;s say all that JSon is y, to access weather=y.weather[1], this should return what you want

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the `weather` key then use indices to get into the list, then do gets on the items you want.

```
data = {'base': 'stations',
 'clouds': {'all': 90},
 'cod': 200,
 'coord': {'lat': 40.73, 'lon': -73.99},
 'dt': 1557824237,
 'id': 5128581,
 'main': {'humidity': 93,
          'pressure': 1009,
          'temp': 43.93,
          'temp_max': 46,
          'temp_min': 42.01},
 'name': 'New York',
 'sys': {'country': 'US',
         'id': 4026,
         'message': 0.0144,
         'sunrise': 1557826807,
         'sunset': 1557878678,
         'type': 1},
 'visibility': 12874,
 'weather': [{'description': 'mist', 'icon': '50n', 'id': 701, 'main': 'Mist'},
             {'description': 'light intensity drizzle',
              'icon': '09n',
              'id': 300,
              'main': 'Drizzle'}],
 'wind': {'deg': 20, 'speed': 8.05}}


print(data.get('weather')[0].get('description'))
print(data.get('weather')[0].get('icon'))
print(data.get('weather')[0].get('id'))
```